# MS SQL -- abs difference of a column with two values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, select

The question I have about sql is :

I have a temp table with two values in the column salary(say 92 and 34). How can i calculate the absolute difference of the column and put it in a new column in the same temp table?

Comment: This post shows no research or effort on your part.

Comment: You cannot put two values in one column.

Answer (score 2):

You want [SQL Server mathematical function `ABS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Assuming that existing values are stored in `col1` and `col2`, and that you want to fill in `new_col` with the absolute difference, you can do:

```
update mytable set new_col = abs(col1 - col2)
```

Comment: and what if they are in the same column?

Comment: What do you mean *in the same column*?